# What's the difference between data-th-text and th:text in Spring thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new in spring thymeleaf and I am not able to get difference between these two `data-th-text` and `th:text`.

Can anyone explain the difference, with the help of examples, and when should I use `data-th-text` and `th:text` ?

Comment: Please add some code ?

Comment: @Hemant <label data-th-text="#{expense.create.title}"></label>

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both does the same thing but as per thymeleaf docs:

> Non-standard attributes we are using in the `th:*` form are not allowed by the HTML5 specification. To make your templates HTML5-valid use `data-` prefix for attribute names and `hyphen (-)` separators instead of `semi-colons (:)`

Ref: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-texts

This is not HTML5 valid:

```html
 <p th:text="#{home.welcome}">Welcome to our grocery store!</p>
```

This is HTML5 valid:

```html
<p data-th-text="#{home.welcome}">Welcome to our grocery store!</p>
```